# Closing out an httpconnection the correct way

Tags: python, http, httpclient, rpc, httpconnection

I am attempting to write a simple bitcoin blockchain indexer.

I've used the bitcoinlib library which contains an AuthServiceProxy module to connect via RPC.

Here's a snippet of the AuthServiceProxy class

```
            # Callables re-use the connection of the original proxy
            self.__conn = connection
        elif self.__url.scheme == 'https':
            self.__conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.__url.hostname, port,
                                                  timeout=timeout)
        else:
            self.__conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(self.__url.hostname, port,
                                                 timeout=timeout)
```

I am creating connections in a loop to retrieve the hash of each block, but due to some socket limits am getting this error after about ~16000 iterations

[WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

My attempt to solve this error was to do this:

```
        while block_counter < total_blocks:
            block_hash = rpc_connection.getblockhash(total_blocks)
            blockHashArray = np.append(blockHashArray, block_hash)
            rpcConnector.close(rpc_connection)
```

```
def close(rpc_connection):
    rpc_connection._AuthServiceProxy__conn.close()
```

It didn't seem to have any affect, so I am wondering what I am missing.